# SQL Server Remote Connections Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Getting Error Message in Creating Remote SQL Connections but works fine in Local Connections

**Error Message:**

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. (System.Data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not sure what has happened in your case but you may try

changing the references System.Data.SqlClient in the project

When a project is moved to a new machine,  Sometime need to renew all the references added in that project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Reset Windows Layout. This will solve your problem.

If you refer [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/90949d68-a611-467c-b438-be97b8ab250b) link, you will find that, person having the same problem.

Go through discussion and do the Reset Windows Layout trick.

Hope its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Please, reinstall framework 4.0 or 4.5 from control panel, because 
framework may be is  corrupted.
```